# unable to gps data serially in raspi 4

Tags: pi-4, serial, ubuntu, uart, gps

I am trying to get ublox zed f9p module work with raspi 4. I am using [this module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15136)

I am running on ubuntu 20.04 desktop version on raspi 4 and i have connected the module serially(`/dev/ttyS0)` to my raspi 4. When i do `sudo cat /dev/ttyS0`, I get stream of data initially but later I get this weird messages `$GNTXT,01,01,01,NMEA unknown msg*46.`

I am sure that i have done serial configurations correctly on raspi-config and my wiring is correct too(works in nano).

I have found in other threads running this `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -echo` solved problem for many but it didnot work for me.
I have also tried disabling bluetooth but no luck.

also when i try to parse the data in python using `serial.serial`, i get the stream of data initially but then it throws `input/output error`.

i tried debugging it through dmesg but it doesnot show any error with respect to
dev/ttyS0.

```
$ dmesg | grep /dev/ttyS0

[    0.000000] Kernel command line:  coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=640 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=480 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:8E:99:AC vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc quiet splash
[    1.685255] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    1.685287] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 16, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
[    1.691208] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[  154.826729] ttyS ttyS0: 1 input overrun(s)
```

However the module works well if i connect it through usb.
some insights on this would be helpful.

Comment: My experience is that using Windows newbie friendly Ublox U-centre starts up smoothly, while Rpi4B Linux CLI GPSS tools have a very steep learning curve.

(1) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/557417/what-kind-of-gps-battery-can-i-use-for-ublox-neo-m8n-gps-module
(2) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519711/gps-taking-long-time-to-fix-out-in-the-open

Comment: you reckon its the problem with power supply?

Comment: No I did not hint that power supply might be a problem.  I think it is very unlikely. I noticed that you said USB works.  This is a big tip. I would forget Rpi4B on board serial ports., and try USB serial port first. ubuntu 20.04  might also have a teething problem. I still recommend the evil guy Windows. NEO9 might have some tricks with Widnows, and they don't care about Linux. I did have a painful experience messing with CLI．

Comment: ultimately were you able to figure out a solution for your ubuntu 20.04 and raspi4?

Comment: Well (1) Mine is Matek M9N: https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z09.2.0.0.29e92e8dnHBjD8&id=638883346011&_u=g3thdsb9e5e, (2) I have been using Win10 Ublox U-centre and Rpi4B USB serial ports successfully. ***I have not tried ubuntu 20***. So I am only suggesting some troubleshoot tricks.

Comment: I see, thanks mate! I will better switch back to jetson

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to somehow figure out the solution for it.
it was because of this `serial-getty@ttyS0.service` which was blocking any other data from ttyS0.
Just do the following:

```
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service
sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

and you are good to go.

```
NOTE: This is only tested for serial port(/dev/ttyS0) in raspi 4B with ubuntu 20.04.
```

Comment: How nice you have found the way to go.  Very good news for ubuntu fans.

Comment: Thanks mate! hope the needy ones find this thread